# Inserting data in a string embeddedset/list in OrientDB

Tags: sql, list, sql-update, orientdb

I have an OrientDB database with a class that has an `EMBEDDEDSET`/`EMBEDDEDLIST` field, and I need to update that field every time I change something, like a record log.

I'm using a normal `insert`:

```
insert into order set ..., logLikeField = "A new value"
```

By doing this the new value replaces the old ones, and what I need is to add it to the list but I can't find out how to do that within the docs.

Right now I'm taking the list out and adding the new value and replacing the old list (first a `select` then the `update`), but I don't like it, and I need to do it with the least possible queries.

By the way i'm using Java (w/o JDBC).

[EDIT]

As suggested in the answer below i used:

```
insert into order add logLikeField = "A new value"
```

It worked fine in the OrientDB Studio, but it does nothing when i call it from my program.

This is the code (language spanish):

```
db.command(command("update ordenes set fecha = ?, numero = ?, producto = ? where @rid = " + orden.id)).execute(orden.fecha, orden.numero, orden.producto);
db.command(command("update ordenes add registro = ? where @rid = " + orden.id)).execute(registro);
```

I wanted a one line solution but as long as it is not a select it's good.

This is the command method:

```
public OCommandSQL command(sql){
    return new OCommandSQL(sql);
}
```

the first command does the job correctly but with the other one I get nothing, not even an exception.

What's wrong with my approach? could it be a bug?

OrientDB 1.3.0 - Java 1.7.0 - Windows 7 64

Comment: In OrientDB 3.x, the ADD option is not available, refer[ to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73956862/3883475)

Answer (score 7):

```
update order add logLikeField = "A new value"
```

Comment: Thanks. This partially worked for me. i don't know whats wrong, on the OrientDB Studio it works fine, but in my software it does nothing(the same query).

Comment: Ho did you call the SQL?