# Updating a embedded list in orient db using query

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

```
update Orders ADD orders = [{
                "source":"A",
                "target": ["B", "C"]
                }] where id=1
```

I am trying to add some values into an embedded list, here the embedded list being orders, this is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this to insert some values to the embedded list

```
INSERT INTO SOrders SET orders = [{"source":"A","target": ["B", "C"]}, 
                                  {"source":"B","target": ["E", "F"]}
                                 ] where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In OrientDB 3.x, the 'ADD' option in UPDATE statement is not available

The way to add to set/list etc. is to use the SQL functions. Refer: [SQL Function Reference](https://orientdb.org/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Functions.html).

In the above case, to add to a list the list() function could be used. Below is an example:

```
UPDATE #62:0 SET category=list(category,'y');
```

In the above example, if the category property has value, the value 'y' will be merged into the list. If category is not set 'y' will be set in a list

```
UPDATE #62:0 SET category=set(category,'y');
```

Similar to the above, set also can be inserted into.